# 10 Days Unconfirmed. Transaction Fr. Blockchain Wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I sent a transaction on Dec 12. It is now the 22 and its still unconfirmed. I paid $17 in miner's fees... and still. 10 days later its still stuck. I've tried ViaBtc, and Antpool accelerator to no avail. Still stuck. PushTx.Btc is $500 as are two other services I tried. Not sure what to do.

tx
24f2df7d517dbf03447a279a1d3f6e5db82fc1760cf78178b0a7bf80a35389d0

Please help

PS> I have written to Blockhain, and they said they do not accelerate nor confirm transactions

PSPS> CPFP: Does this mean that I send more money to the SAME wallet address and pay more on the second transaction?

Comment: First, which of the receiver address is yours? And is it an exchange wallet address?

Comment: CPFP will cost you a lot, I did an estimate for you (((824Sat/Byte) / 100000000) * (1702Bytes + 192Bytes)) - 0.000853BTC = your new transaction is going to cost you in total 0.01475356BTC. That equals to 7684Sat/Bytes. This should cover for both parents and child.

Comment: I sent bitcoin To:

1B1qvcXkYQfEmJhabYB4nM12LRwCZ14GG2 I am sending it from a wallet to an exchange.

Comment: Unfortunately the chance is slim that you can do a CPFP if you sent to an exchange. Most, if not all exchanges don't allow it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying that I would need to send another transaction to the SAME address listed above 1B1qv (etc) and send that transaction with a fee of 0.015 bitcoin??? Omg.

Comment: No, you would need to send a transaction with 1B1qvcXkYQfEmJhabYB4nM12LRwCZ14GG2 (parent) as the sender to another address (child).

Comment: What should I do?  I've contacted the exchange. No reply in more than 7 days.

Comment: The only viable option you have left is to wait it out, or [ask some members on bitcointalk.org for their free transaction accelerator services](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=52.0) or maybe even go for the paid services( but be aware of the scammy ones).

Comment: What is the longest you've heard of someone's transaction being stuck? I'm afraid it may be stuck for months or years and anything can happen to the blockchain, wallets, and bitcoins in the interim. Look at today. $7K Drop :(

Comment: Honestly is difficult to say, if the incoming waves of transactions decrease in the upcoming days your transactions stand a chance to be confirmed. If not, maybe dropped in  1 - infinite weeks time.

Comment: I recommend you post on bitcointalk.org where the members have announced their services, I have good experience with their services. Some of them have access to a variety of pools.

Comment: Thank you so much. On there now. Its hard to differentiate scam from real. 100's of pages. People arguing back & forth. Sighhhh....

Comment: Go for the ones with the most views and replies, and look through the last 2 pages if transactions have been accelerated recently. Well, is free anyway, so wouldn't hurt.